# I want a user to only access download url for pdf if the user exists in order table models how can I do it?

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

Here is my view function where i have tried to excute the functionality

```
@login_required
def secure_pdf(request,file):
    user = get_object_or_404(User)
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=user).all()
    
    if user in order:
        document = get_object_or_404(Exam,pdf='pdf/'+file)
        path,file_name = os.path.split(file)
        response = FileResponse(document.pdf)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("acess denied")
```

my order model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders', blank=True, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    tx_ref = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: please try to write code from project with error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read a little bit more about Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/

at first. If you use authentication from django:

```
user = request.user
```

At second. What you mean `if user in order`. User cannot be in list of orders. user is User model and order is Order model. Something really wrong in your logic.

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user).all()  # this is list of orders
```

orders - is already filtered by user list of orders.

```
if orders.count():
    ...
```

or

```
if orders.exists():
    ...
```

You can use oredrs.get, orders.list, orders.first. But you don't use it anywhere. And all what happens in **if clause** is not readable. Exam? File? Path? file_name? What you want to do?